# How to write a custom function in linq clause

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a custom function in linq like that.

```
private short GetSignByEntityType(string entityType, InvoiceReportType invoiceReportType)
{
    if (invoiceReportType == InvoiceReportType.WithholdingTaxReport)
    {
        if (entityType == "R") return 1;
        if (entityType == "I") return -1;
    }
    return this._sign;
}

var headerDataWithBook1Rates = (
from hd in headerDataToUse
from vi in voucherItems.Where(x => x.VoucherID == hd.VoucherID && x.Sign == GetSignByEntityType(hd.EntityType, request.ReportType)).DefaultIfEmpty()
from dvi in draftVoucherItems.Where(x => x.DraftVoucherID == -hd.VoucherID && x.Sign == GetSignByEntityType(hd.EntityType, request.ReportType)).DefaultIfEmpty()
from vacc in accounts.Where(x => x.ID == vi.AccountID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from dvacc in accounts.Where(x => x.ID == dvi.AccountID).DefaultIfEmpty()
.....
```

it gives me an error.

> System.NotSupportedException: Method 'Int16
>   GetSignByEntityType(System.String,
>   Enka.Gfs.Domain.SharedEntities.Request.InvoiceReportType)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You could do this if you were using pure LINQ, but you are using EntityFramework / Linq-to-SQL. It is trying to execute your function on the SQL server, which obviously has no idea what `GetSignByEntityType()` means.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this cannot be done in this manner. You are essentially trying to run your custom C# function on the SQL server, which will not work. A way you can solve this is by writing a SQL stored procedure on your SQL server which does what you want and then calling that stored procedure using the Entity Framework in C#.

This documentation may help: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Why do you say "Sadly"?

Comment: Well it would be real nice if you could execute C# code on a SQL server as a stored procedure, but that would require a way to convert between C# and SQL in a very complex way. Entity Framework doesn't do something like that, and it may not really be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving your task, First you can use Stored procedures and create your functions to execute on the db side. Second is to create a sql views (using sql views is very well explained [here](http://kamoga.net/using-an-sql-view-with-entity-framework-code-first/))

Either way your best call is to convert your c# code into sql queries and execute them form the database side and get back processed data sets.